# Update failed: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: apex, unit-test, permissions, sharing, sharing-rule

I have three test classes in my org which are not executing. For those three classes I'm facing same error. After analyzed three classes I'm having same problem with account.

[image]

When i comment the insert account for the first class and Upsert account for second class and update for third class,these are working fine. But these classes are working fine in another sandbox without commenting those lines.

I've checked permission for the user i created. The user have proper permissions.

This is the first first class method where i'm facing error at insert Con.

```
private static final string CPP_ADMIN_MANAGER = 'CommScope CPP Admin Manager';

    oldPartnerUser = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestUser(2,cppUserProfileID);
    oldPartnerUser.contactId = contactsList.get(1).Id;
    insert oldPartnerUser;

    System.runAs(oldPartnerUser) { 

        acc = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestAccount(1);    
        acc.Vertical_Markets__c = 'Carrier';  
        acc.ownerId =  oldPartnerUser.Id;   
        insert acc;

        System.debug('oldPartnerUser owner : ' + acc.ownerId + ' ' + acc.owner.name);
        AccountTeamMember atmForPAM = new AccountTeamMember(AccountId = acc.Id,
        TeamMemberRole = 'Partner Account Manager', UserId = sysadminuser1.Id); 
        //insert atmForPAM;

        con = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestContact(5);
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;            
        con.Email = 'testcon5@domain.com';
        con.ownerId =  oldPartnerUser.Id; 
        insert con;
```

Second class method(error at update manRebate;)

```
cppuser = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestUser(1,CPPprofID);
        cppuser.contactId = con.Id;
        cppuser.UserRoleId = urole.Id;
        insert cppuser;


     system.runAs(cppuser){ //start run as
        Test.startTest();
            Account acc2 = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestAccount(3);
            insert acc2;

            Rebate__c manRebate = new Rebate__c(RecordTypeId = RECORD_TYPE_ID_MANUAL_REBATE,
                                                 Account__c = acc.Id,
                                                 Notes__c = ' ',
                                                 Notes_Internal__c = 'This is manual rebate for ',
                                                 Reason__c = 'NA',
                                                 Status__c = 'Approved'
                                                 );

             insert manRebate;

           manRebate.Account__c = acc2.Id;
             update manRebate;
         Test.stopTest();

    }//end od run as
}
```

What could be the reason for working in one org and not working in another org. Can anyone please help me to find the problem.

Comment: In the second class i'm seeing the RecordType is enabled for Rebate__c.check that user's profile has access to them.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Frodo Profile can access that record type.

Comment: Can you run the test classes again by checking the "Disable Parallel Apex Testing"?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo The option "Disable Parallel Apex Testing" is already checked. I unchecked and tested, even same error ,